# Your TabHost must have a TabWidget whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabs'

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

When trying to setup my TabHost, I get an exception, due to this: "Your TabHost must have a TabWidget whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabs'"

I reverted to the example of minimal tab Host/widget and FrameLayout in my xml file  (with Tabwidget using android:id="@android:id/tabs") I have tried cleaning my project, deleting my R file, restarting eclipse and my machine (OSX Lion, indigo, r20) but this error keeps coming back. Any tips welcome.
TIA

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and supply the layout file. Or, examine this sample project for one that works: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/Tab

Comment: Try the project that I linked to.

Comment: Got it fixed, my instanciation of the TabHost was wrong. Many thanks.